# Where to find people interested in contributing to an open source project?

Tags: contributor, community

A few contributors and I are working on a large-scale Ethereum app called the Decentralized News Network (http://dnn.media), or DNN. The application itself will be entirely open source and we are trying to figure out where to gain more interest from the open source community.

If anyone knows of where we can enlist support from the open source community, it would be appreciated greatly!

**Updated**: I updated the phrasing of my question. I apologize if the original wording seemed to come across too much like an announcement.

Comment: The only way you can enlist support is when you have actual code released. This board is neither an announce forum nor a place to prop free, libre or open source projects. As a side note using Slack for an open source project is a terribly bad choice. You should consider IRC, irccloud, eventually gitter, but not a walled garden like slack if you want to get any community traction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my question to remove the background details. I just linked the site. Thanks for your suggestions. In the future I'll be sure not to word my questions like an announcement. The last thing I want to do is get down voted.

Comment: I feel bad for only seeing this 8 days later... but I just saw this in the review queues. I do have one suggestion for your question, that would word it much more objectively. Instead of asking *where* you can find people (many people don't like that part), perhaps you could ask *how* you can find people? In other words, instead of looking for a particular website or something, you could ask for specific strategies in reaching out to people? It's a little bit difficult for me to give any concrete advice - we're not exactly used to these kinds of questions, but that said, I love the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the question should be the other way around: How does people interested in Open Source development find you and your projects? My answer would be: be visible and provide easy ways to get engaged.

Being visible means to have a good homepage which explains the project as good as possible, write about it on blogs, news pages, social networks, go to conferences, etc. Release early & release often. Also it is important to work in the open. Even if you are alone. Have a public repository right from the beginning, make pull requests so that people can see the code, the work and the workflow. This makes it more likely that people will join you.

Providing easy ways to engage means to have public mailing lists, maybe a forum, issue tracker and an IRC channel. I would also recommend to focus on open and free communication channels.

Then, if people find you, you need to start to build a community. Response to emails, forum entries, issues, etc. Tell people how they can help. Review pull requests in time and guide the people to other issues by asking them to review your or other pull requests. Trust people by giving them merge rights as soon as possible.

Hope this contain some useful tips.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your response. This was extremely helpful. You're exactly right, I think the issue was the order of my questioning. Rather than seek people, the project should be easily accessible, and available to those that want to contribute. Not sure why my question got downvoted. Didn't intend to come across like I'm marketing. Just wanted to give as much details about the project as possible.Thanks again!

Comment: @DondreyTaylor: sorry but yes, it looked like you used the board as an announcement platform. Too much info on your project and too little about the actual question.